# Why two distinct colors on this object?

Tags: materials

my probllem simply is I am creating a hand saw and the handle, which is one object, clearly looks divided with two different colors.

I did nothing in Shading workspace, only Materials...New...Color and selected the lighter red shown, but get an additional red. I don't get it. :)  Yes still fairly new to this vast product. Thanks for any help.
the pic does show some of the Cycles render properties, all default.

[image: Screen print from blender]

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Seems like a case of autosmooth or subdivision surface modifier, and incorrect normal directions.  Select all verts with A, and then Alt + N -> Recalculate Outside

Comment: This question was closed (which is not a mark against you) because a duplicate question and answer was linked.  If the solution there doesn't help you please come back and [edit] your question to give more details and tell us what did or didn't happen for you.